# How can I improve print speed with carbon fiber nylon and an 0.4 mm nozzle?

Tags: extrusion, nozzle, speed, nylon, carbon

I have been trying to print fiber-filled nylons (Polymaker PA6GF and Taulman PA CF) on my Prusa i3 MK3S+ with a steel E3D 0.4 mm nozzle at a reasonable speed. I print at 290 °C for the Polymaker and 265 °C for the Taulman. This is at the upper end of the specified print temperature range. I can only print up to 25 mm/s before the extruder gears slip and never regain traction. They are tightened pretty much all the way (not that it makes much of a difference). Can the print speed be improved somehow without moving to a larger nozzle, or is this the limit? I was thinking a bimetal nozzle or maybe even a volcano-length nozzle with nuts might improve the viscosity. I would like to get up to maybe 50 mm/s.

Comment: I emailed polymaker and the rep said a volcano style hotend should help. I ordered a plated copper melt zone extender to try out as I don't have a standard volcano heater block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a nickel plated copper meltzone extender which solved the problem. I was able to print a decent benchy with the fastest print speeds at 70 mm/s. The melt zone extender results in the same melt zone length as a volcano nozzle in a normal v6 heater block. A volcano nozzle with an adapter or just a couple m6 brass nuts should work the same. I got the Polymaker filament to work but not the Taulman. I would avoid it.